# Android kotlin: Getting EACCES (Permission denied) even after giving permissions

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, storage

I am developing an android app and having trouble with the permission handling (API lvl 30, Android ver. 11)

I tried to follow the steps here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

When using the "checkSelfPermission()" function, it looks like I have the necessary permissions, but when trying to Write to a file I get the error which is shown in the log on the bottom of this post.

This is my code:

```
class FilesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            Log.d("access granted", isGranted.toString())

        } else {
            Log.d("access granted", isGranted.toString())
        }
    }


private lateinit var binding: ActivityFilesBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)




    requestPermissions()
```

The method which checks the permissions looks like this:

```
    private fun requestPermissions() {
    when {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
            Log.d("Permission","Already granted")
        }
        else -> {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I get the Permissions-prompt and after granting permission I try to download a file. The code for downloading the file is in an adapter-class for a recyclerview.

```
                    try{
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        mContext,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        val myFile = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),file.getFilename()!!)
                        val fileRef = Firebase.storage.getReferenceFromUrl(file.getUrl()!!)

                        fileRef.getFile(myFile).addOnSuccessListener {
                            // Local temp file has been created
                            Toast.makeText(mContext,"File downloaded to Downloads Dir.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }.addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext,it.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }

                } catch(e :Error){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
```

I am not sure, what I did wrong.
Maybe someone here can help me.
Thanks in advance

Edit: My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/round_logo_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_logo_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.app">
    <activity android:name=".UserRatingsActivity"></activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".ui.myFiles.FilesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_files"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StuddyV0_1.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".Register" />
    <activity android:name=".EnterCourses" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".PushNotifications.FirebaseService"
        android:permission="com.google.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".NotificationsPckg.MyFirebaseMessaging"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

And in the settings of my phone I can see that the app has permissions to access storage.

Edit: It is working in the emulator but not on a real phone. (Galaxy s20)

the log looks like this:

```
E/FileDownloadTask: Exception occurred during file write.  Aborting.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/SKE_Labor.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:147)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8494)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236) 
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:147) 
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228) 
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072) 
    at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
    /storage/emulated/0/Download/SKE_Labor.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/SKE_Labor.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:147)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8494)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:147) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
    /storage/emulated/0/Download/SKE_Labor.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/SKE_Labor.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:147)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8494)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:147) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Edit: After coming back to this problem I noticed, it only occurs with .pdf files. everything else is downloaded and saved properly.

Comment: If you go to the settings for your app you can see if you indeed have the write permission.
        `

Comment: `Android kotlin: Getting EACCES (Permission denied) ..` It is unclear for which file that would be. For a file to be created on your device or for a file in your Firebase.

Comment: it is for a file that I am creating before downloading to write the download to the file. "val myFile"

Comment: `val myFile = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),file.getFilename()!! ` You create a File instance. That does not create a file. So cannot cause the failed acces. Please investigate.

Comment: I thought it would be this line: "fileRef.getFile(myFile).addOnSuccessListener" causing the error.
Btw: its working in the emulator but not on my real phone

Comment: Yes its that line. Now answer my question about to which file there is no access. Post the logcat lines!

Comment: `but when trying to Write to a file I get the error mentioned above.` How are you shure that it is writing to a file? Why not reading from the firebase file? And please do not refer to the subject of your post.

Comment: because of this line `E/FileDownloadTask: Exception occurred during file write.  Aborting` .
Excuse me for any mistakes.

Comment: Do a test where your app itself creates and writes to the file. No need to use fitebase code. Just try to creatr a file.

Comment: (Galaxy s20) Android version please. Also of emulator  Does your file already exist? Then remove it first. if(myFile.exists())if(!myFile.delete()) return:

Comment: I just tested it a minute ago where I moved the creating of file and downloading to the FilesActivity instead of the Adapter Class. This worked and I got my file in the downloads directory.
I can do further testing later.

Comment: I also did it in a "fresh" emulator after wiping the user data.

Comment: Its android version 11

Answer (score 0):

Extends ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback is not available in FilesActivity class.

```
class FilesActivity : AppCompatActivity() , ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
}
```

You need to call the ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback interface for the requestPermissionLauncher definition.

Sample Code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {


private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission has been granted. Start camera preview Activity.

                startCamera()

        } else {
            // Permission request was denied.
            requestPermissions()
        }
    }



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    requestPermissions()


}

private fun requestPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission has been granted. Start camera preview Activity.
        startCamera()

    } else  requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
}


private fun startCamera() {
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

}

https://github.com/harunkor/requestPermissionLauncherSample

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does work, when I download the file in the FilesActivity. But I want to donwload the file with a function in a FilesAdapter class for a recyclerview as stated above.
I still check for permissions there, but no luck.

Comment: That makes no sense. It does not matter where you ask and get a permission. It will be valid for the whole app for its life time. Only download and write after getting the permission. You can do that the next day to be shure ;-).

Comment: Thanks for all your help but in the code of the adapter class I already posted, I am checking the permission before downloading. Did I do anything wrong there? I know it makes no sense.